# 1ページに表示する最大投稿数とWP_Queryで指定するpost_per_pageの値が異なるときのページングの問題

Tags: wordpress

設定→表示設定→1ページに表示する最大投稿数には `10` と入力してあり、`WP_Query` では

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
  'posts_per_page' => 8
]);
?>
```

のように `8` としています。
また、ページネーションは

```
<?php
pagination([
  'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
]);
?>
```

のようにしています。

現在、記事が20件あり1ページに8件ずつ表示すると3ページ目が4件となります。3ページ目にアクセスすると、記事一覧は表示されますがページのタイトルは「ページが見つかりません」となっており（本来は3ページ目と表示されなければならない）、ページネーションも表示されなくなってしまいます。

解決方法があれば教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: トップ、アーカイブ等のメインループであればfilterでメインループのクエリを弄るべきで別途クエリを走らすべきでない、というのはあります。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。色々調べていくうちに、`pre_get_posts` でクエリ実行前に操作する方法があるみたいなのでそれを使います。